# Sticky navbar not positioning correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navbar that I want to stick to the top of the screen when I scroll past it's top coordinates. I am trying to achieve this by adding a class to it using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
            $('#nav').addClass('nav-fixed');
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 801) {
            $('#nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the class that I am adding:

```
.nav-fixed {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

This is before scroll:
[image: before]

This is after scroll:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `width: 100%`

```
.nav-fixed {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```